# retrieving image from database in wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, xaml

I have a simple application that contains a `Login` Window and another Window called `Principal`. In my SQL Server database there is a `tbl_user` with the following columns:

- `pmk_int_user`,
- `name_str_user`,
- `user_str_user`,
- `pass_str_user`,
- `photo_img_user`
  Type Image.

In my Principal WPF Xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="71" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Name="Photo"/>
</Grid>
```

And my Login WPF XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2"
     Grid.Row="1"
     Name="txtUser"
     Margin="4"/>

<PasswordBox Grid.Column="2"
     Grid.Row="2"
     Name="txtPass"
     Margin="4"/>

<Button Name="btnLogin"
    Content="Login"
    Width="60"
    Height="30"
    Margin="4"
    IsDefault="True"
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Login"
    Click="btn_login">
</Button>
```

My Login Code Behind:

```
private void btn_login(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUser.Text != "") 
    {
        if (txtPass.Password != "")
        {

            _con = new SqlConnection(_strConexao);

            _con.Open();
            string user_str_user = txtUser.Text;
            string user_str_user = txtPass.Password;
            string query = "select * from tbl_user where user_str_user='" + this.txtUser.Text + "' and pass_str_user='" + this.txtPass.Password + "'";
            _cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _con);
            _dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader();


            string _name;
            string _data;
            int _id;
            byte[] _photo;

            if (_dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (_dr.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _id = _dr.GetInt32(0);
                        _name = _dr.GetString(1);
                        _data = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                        _photo = (byte[])_dr[3];
                        Principal p = new Principal();
                        p.ID.Text = _id.ToString();
                        p.Nome.Text = _name;
                        p.Data.Text = _data;

                        MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(_Photo);
                        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);
                        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                        bi.BeginInit();
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        bi.StreamSource = ms;
                        bi.EndInit();
                        p.Photo.Source = bi;
                        p.Show();
                        this.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
```

But when I click, and login using a valid user and password it shows `an invalid parameter`. When I comments this code:

```
MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(_photo);
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();
p.Photo.Source = bi;
```

This code is just open File Dialoge to choose Image:

```
private void btnAddFoto(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog _fd = new OpenFileDialog();
            byte[] dadosImagem = null;
            if (_fd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    _fs = new FileStream(_fd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    dadosImagem = new byte[_fs.Length];
                    _fs.Read(dadosImagem, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(_fs.Length));
                    _fs.Close();

                    ImageSourceConverter imgs = new ImageSourceConverter();
                    imgPessoa.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, imgs.ConvertFromString(_fd.FileName.ToString()));


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Erro :: " + ex.Message);
                }
}
```

This is to Convert:

```
private byte[] BitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapSource image)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(); 
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
                encoder.Save(stream);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

And this is to get image from Image Control and save on database:

```
var foto_img_pessoa = BitmapSourceToByteArray((BitmapSource)imgPessoa.Source);
```

It works, but my image is not displayed in my `Principal` Window. What is the problem in this code? 
My error message exception is: `{System.ArgumentException: Parâmetro inválido. em System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData) em System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)`

Comment: Can you step through the code?  Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: I also am not sure why you do not just initialize the bitmap with the stream you get from the database.  You should not need to save the Bitmap and then load the image from the other.  What type of image is saved in the database?  Are you sure it is valid?

Comment: @mageos i add image by this methodo `private void btnAddPhoto(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { _fs = new FileStream(_fd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    img = new byte[_fs.Length];
                    _fs.Read(img, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(_fs.Length));
                    _fs.Close();
ImageSourceConverter imgs = new ImageSourceConverter();
                    imgUser.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, imgs.ConvertFromString(_fd.FileName.ToString()));}} ` after this i save it binary image in my database; my problem is now how to retrieve it from database.

Comment: @mageos my error line is `System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);` when i debug in this line is point as errror and pass to catch (Exception ex)

Comment: I would double check the data in the database.  I use that same method all the time to convert byte[] to images.  My guess is that the data in the database is corrupt.  Have you confirmed that _photo has a value.  Looking at the code, it also appears you may have a typeo.  Try using _photo instead of _Photo in the MemoryStream

Comment: @mageos sorry fixed MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(_photo); but just same error message is show invalid parameter exception.

Comment: What's your error code?  Put it in your question.

Comment: @cullub my error is `{System.ArgumentException: Parâmetro inválido.
   em System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   em System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)` in this code line: `System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Witch is the bast way to save image and retrive it from database? I just look in several tutorials but any work for me. in my case i simple setting a texblock hidden with a id value and based on this id i would select a image from database. But doesn't work.

Comment: Your edit is very confusing. It is entirely unclear where exactly you get which exception. And where is the sense in reading the image file into a buffer (dadosImagem) when you don't use it later. That doesn't make sense. Try to reduce your post to the shortest possible but complete code that reproduces your problem. Perhaps remove this question and write a new one.